# Why does a person need to be connected to the ground to perform kishuf (magic)?

Tags: sorcery-magic-kishuf

The gemarah (Yerushlmi Hagigah 2:2, Sanhedrin 6:6) recounts a story of Shimon ben Shetach who captured 80 witches. In the story he instructs those assisting him to lift the witches off the ground to prevent them from being able to use their magic. Similarly according to the Daas Zekeinim (Shemos 8:14) the reason Pharaoh's sorcerers couldn't replicate the plague of lice was because they were not on the ground.

I would like to know why it is that a person needs to be directly connected to the ground in order to perform kishuf (magic).

Comment: Would history of this belief, showing other sources from antiquity that believed this, explaining where Hazal got it from, constitute an answer?

Comment: @mevaqesh I believe so

Comment: Related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1715/603

Comment: mskst kinim... ...

Comment: The first recorded witchhunt... Did he end up killing these witches?

Comment: @ElShteiger yes, all on the same day in fact